# React hooks updating component after value inside object inside another object changes - how to?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested, react-hooks

I'm trying to get a functional component to rerender after one of the values in an object that's in an object changes:

So project has tasks: **project.tasks** and **project.completed_tasks**

Each task is also an object that has an attribute is_completed: **task.is_completed**

Once the is_completed changes to true or false i want the **Project** componet to re-render with the updated progress of the tasks.

This works on the back end but i cannot get this to work with React and hooks api. I'm guessing it has to do with **shallow comparison vs deep comparison** but im already creating a copy in the **updateTask** function in tasksContext.

Any help would be appreciated! Bolded so that it is easier to read since it's a lot.

Here is my component that i want to change:

```
const Project = ({project, formatDate}) => {
    const tasksContext = useContext(TasksContext);
    const {tasksCompleted} = tasksContext;
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [progress] = useState(tasksCompleted.filter(task => task.project_id === project.id).length);

 return (
            <Card.Content>
                <Card.Header>
                    {project.name}
                </Card.Header>
                <Card.Meta>
                    {formatDate(project.start_date)} - {formatDate(project.end_date)}
                </Card.Meta>
                <Card.Description>
                <Progress value={progress} total={project.total_tasks} progress='ratio' warning/>
                </Card.Description>
            </Card.Content>
            <Card.Content extra>
                <List celled horizontal size="mini" floated="right">
                    <List.Item as="a" onClick={handleEdit}>Edit</List.Item>
                    <List.Item as="a" onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</List.Item>
                </List>
                <Confirm
                    open={open}
                    onCancel={handleCancel}
                    onConfirm={handleConfirm}
                    cancelButton='Never mind'
                    confirmButton="Let's do it" 
                    size='mini'
                />
            </Card.Content>
    )
};
```

Here is my tasksContext hook:

```
import React, {createContext, useState} from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export const TasksContext = createContext({});

export const TasksProvider = props => {
    //initial values obtained from props
    const {
        tasks: initialTasks,
        tasksCompleted: initialTasksCompleted,
        children
    } = props;

    //state to keep the values
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(initialTasks);
    const [tasksCompleted, setTasksCompleted] = useState(initialTasksCompleted);

    //============== TASK FUNCTIONS ===================//
    const getTasks = () => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        const getObj = {
            'method': 'GET',
            'headers': {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        }
        const tasksUrl = `http://localhost:3000/tasks`;
        fetch(tasksUrl, getObj)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(tasks => {
                setTasks(tasks)
                getTasksCompleted(tasks)
            })
    }

    const getTasksCompleted = (tasks) => {
        const completedTasks = tasks.filter(task => task.is_completed === true);
        setTasksCompleted(completedTasks);
    }

    const updateTask = (task) => {
        const updatedTasks = [...tasks];
        const index = updatedTasks.findIndex(taskToUpdate => taskToUpdate.id === task.id);
        updatedTasks[index] = task;
        setTasks(updatedTasks);
        getTasksCompleted(updatedTasks);
    }

    //make the context object
    const tasksContext = {
        tasks,
        setTasks,
        tasksCompleted,
        getTasks,
        updateTask
    };

    return <TasksContext.Provider value={tasksContext}>{children}</TasksContext.Provider>
};

export const {TasksConsumer} = TasksContext;

TasksProvider.propTypes = {
    tasks: PropTypes.array,
    tasksCompleted: PropTypes.array
};

TasksProvider.defaultProps = {
    tasks: [],
    tasksCompleted: []
};
```

Here is the other component that calls the updateTask function:

```
const Task = ({task}) => {
    const tasksContext = useContext(TasksContext);
    const {updateTask} = tasksContext;
    const [name, setName] = useState(task.name);
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(task.is_completed);
    const [editing, setEditing] = useState(task.name ? false : true);

    const editTask = (name, is_completed) => {
        const taskUrl = `http://localhost:3000/tasks/${task.id}`
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        const taskObj = {
            'method': 'PATCH',
            'headers': {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }, 
            'body': JSON.stringify({name, is_completed})
        }
        fetch(taskUrl, taskObj)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(task => {
            setName(name);
            updateTask(task);
        })
    }

...render function etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies in how you keep track of progress in your Project component:

```
const [progress] = useState(tasksCompleted.filter(task => task.project_id === project.id).length);
```

This line only initializes the value of `progress`. If you want the component to rerender, you'll need to change the progress value once `tasksCompleted` changes. Assuming `tasksCompleted`, changes correctly, you can use `useEffect` watch the variable and update `progress` state.

```
const [progress, setProgress] = useState(tasksCompleted.filter(task => task.project_id === project.id).length);

useEffect(() => {
  setProgress(tasksCompleted.filter(task => task.project_id === project.id).length)
}, [tasksCompleted])
```

Function specified in useEffect will run the first time it renders, and everytime a value in the array changes. Since it updates the state, it will also trigger rerender.

Comment: ah this worked, thank you! i am still new to hooks, so learning when to use useEffect has been tripping me up.

Comment: Np, glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

Try `useEffect()` like so in your functional component:

```
const tasksContext = useContext(TasksContext);

useEffect(() => {
    tasksContext
}, [...Object.values(tasksContext]);
```

This will look for changes within the values themselves, and should trigger `useContext()` at the appropriate times.